# Buttons in script are being clicked without my permission. JavaScript trivia game

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been working on getting all this linked up. My trivia game is wrapped in a function and the buttons are firing all on their own, but in order.

So if I click `A` then `#optionB` `#optionC` and `#optionD` fire all on their own. Also I'm only being able to click one option(`#optionA`) for it to render the next question. [Here's a JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/g2w9uemb/). However, the link doesn't properly work like if you were to run it in Visual Studio Code, etc., but all the code is provided in the JSFiddle link, so it's an easy copy and paste, because it's a lot of code I've tried wrapping clicks in a function as you can see, but that didn't solve the issue.

```js
(function() {
  let arr = [$("#optionA"), $("#optionB"), $("#optionC"), $("#optionD")];
  let randArr = arr[Math.floor(arr.length * Math.random())];
  let btnNext = $("#btnNext");
  let answer = randArr;
  let question = "";
  let answerReal;
  let optionA = $("#optionA");
  let optionB = $("#optionB");
  let optionC = $("#optionC");
  let optionD = $("#optionD");
  var count = 0;
  let correct = 0;
  let incorrect = 0;
  let unanswered = 0;
  function startGame() {
    $(btnNext).on("click", function nextQuestion() {
      count++;
      console.log(count);
      if (count === 10) {
        $("#container").hide();
        $("#score").show();
      }
      //   function shuffle() {  // --------- this function was called to randomize my array(var arr), however it's not needed ---
      //     var currentarr = arr.length;
      //     var index, temp;

      //     while (currentarr > 0) {
      //       index = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentarr);
      //       currentarr--;

      //       temp = arr[currentarr];
      //       arr[currentarr] = arr[index];
      //       arr[index] = temp;
      //     }
      //   }
      (function($) {
        // ----------------- this function shuffles all the DOM elements after it's been called (look down below) ------------
        $.fn.shuffle = function() {
          var allElems = this.get(),
            getRandom = function(max) {
              return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
            },
            shuffled = $.map(allElems, function() {
              var random = getRandom(allElems.length),
                randEl = $(allElems[random]).clone(true)[0];
              allElems.splice(random, 1);
              return randEl;
            });

          this.each(function(i) {
            $(this).replaceWith($(shuffled[i]));
          });

          return $(shuffled);
        };
      })(jQuery);
      // ----------------------- here we call the DOM elements to be shuffled---------------------------------------------------
      $("#answers button").shuffle();
      fetch("http://jservice.io/api/random")
        .then(function(response) {
          if (response.status !== 200) {
            console.log(
              "Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: " + response.status
            );
            return;
          }

          // Examine the text in the response
          response.json().then(function(data) {
            //------------------------------FETCHING THE API----------------------------------------------
            console.log(data);
            answerReal = data[0].answer;
            question = data[0].question;
            console.log(question + ": " + answer);
            $("#question").html(question);
            // shuffle($("#answers"));
            console.log(arr);
            $("#optionA").html(answerReal);
            $("#optionA").addClass("secretwinner");
            console.log(answerReal);
          });
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
          console.log("Fetch Error :-S", err);
        });
      fetch("http://jservice.io/api/random")
        .then(function(response) {
          if (response.status !== 200) {
            console.log(
              "Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: " + response.status
            );
            return;
          }

          // Examine the text in the response
          response.json().then(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            answerNonReal = data[0].answer;
            $("#optionB").html(answerNonReal);
            $("#optionB").addClass("notasecretwinner");
            console.log(answerNonReal); //-----------------------------FETCHING THE API----------------------------------------
          });
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
          console.log("Fetch Error :-S", err);
        });
      fetch("http://jservice.io/api/random")
        .then(function(response) {
          if (response.status !== 200) {
            console.log(
              "Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: " + response.status
            );
            return;
          }

          // Examine the text in the response
          response.json().then(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            answerNonReal = data[0].answer;
            $("#optionC").html(answerNonReal);
            $("#optionC").addClass("notasecretwinner");
            console.log(answerNonReal); //------------------------------FETCHING THE API---------------------------------------
          });
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
          console.log("Fetch Error :-S", err);
        });
      fetch("http://jservice.io/api/random")
        .then(function(response) {
          if (response.status !== 200) {
            console.log(
              "Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: " + response.status
            );
            return;
          }

          // Examine the text in the response
          response.json().then(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            answerNonReal = data[0].answer;
            $("#optionD").html(answerNonReal);
            $("#optionD").addClass("notasecretwinner");
            console.log(answerNonReal); //-------------------------------FETCHING THE API--------------------------------------
          });
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
          console.log("Fetch Error :-S", err);
        });
    });
  } //---------------------------------------------------------END-------------------------------------------------------------
  function renderQuestion() {
    count++;
    console.log(count);
    if (count === 10) {
      $("#container").hide();
      $("#score").show();
    }
    (function($) {
      // ----------------- This function shuffles all the DOM elements after its been called (look down below) ------------
      $.fn.shuffle = function() {
        var allElems = this.get(),
          getRandom = function(max) {
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
          },
          shuffled = $.map(allElems, function() {
            var random = getRandom(allElems.length),
              randEl = $(allElems[random]).clone(true)[0];
            allElems.splice(random, 1);
            return randEl;
          });

        this.each(function(i) {
          $(this).replaceWith($(shuffled[i]));
        });

        return $(shuffled);
      };
    })(jQuery);
    //-----------------------here we call the DOM elements to be shuffled---------------------------------------------------
    $("#answers button").shuffle();
    fetch("http://jservice.io/api/random")
      .then(function(response) {
        if (response.status !== 200) {
          console.log(
            "Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: " + response.status
          );
          return;
        }

        // Examine the text in the response
        response.json().then(function(data) {
          //------------------------------FETCHING THE API----------------------------------------------
          console.log(data);
          answerReal = data[0].answer;
          question = data[0].question;
          console.log(question + ": " + answer);
          $("#question").html(question);
          console.log(arr);
          $("#optionA").html(answerReal);
          $("#optionA").addClass("secretwinner");
          console.log(answerReal);
        });
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.log("Fetch Error :-S", err);
      });
    fetch("http://jservice.io/api/random")
      .then(function(response) {
        if (response.status !== 200) {
          console.log(
            "Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: " + response.status
          );
          return;
        }

        // Examine the text in the response
        response.json().then(function(data) {
          console.log(data);
          answerNonReal = data[0].answer;
          $("#optionB").html(answerNonReal);
          $("#optionB").addClass("notasecretwinner");
          console.log(answerNonReal); //-----------------------------FETCHING THE API----------------------------------------
        });
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.log("Fetch Error :-S", err);
      });
    fetch("http://jservice.io/api/random")
      .then(function(response) {
        if (response.status !== 200) {
          console.log(
            "Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: " + response.status
          );
          return;
        }

        // Examine the text in the response
        response.json().then(function(data) {
          console.log(data);
          answerNonReal = data[0].answer;
          $("#optionC").html(answerNonReal);
          $("#optionC").addClass("notasecretwinner");
          console.log(answerNonReal); //------------------------------FETCHING THE API---------------------------------------
        });
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.log("Fetch Error :-S", err);
      });
    fetch("http://jservice.io/api/random")
      .then(function(response) {
        if (response.status !== 200) {
          console.log(
            "Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: " + response.status
          );
          return;
        }

        // Examine the text in the response
        response.json().then(function(data) {
          console.log(data);
          answerNonReal = data[0].answer;
          $("#optionD").html(answerNonReal);
          $("#optionD").addClass("notasecretwinner");
          console.log(answerNonReal); //-------------------------------FETCHING THE API--------------------------------------
        });
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.log("Fetch Error :-S", err);
      });
  }
  startGame();
  $("#score").hide();
  startAnswers();
  function startAnswers() {
    $(optionA).on("click", function() {
      console.log("this is the correct button");
      console.log("this button is being clicked A");
      correct++;
      $("#correct").text(correct);
      $("#optionA").addClass("correct-button");
      $("#optionA").removeClass("correct-button");
      renderQuestion();
    });
    $(optionB).on("click", function() {
      console.log("wrong button");
      console.log("this button is being clicked B");
      incorrect++;
      $("#incorrect").text(incorrect);
      $("#optionB").addClass("incorrect-button");
      $("#optionB").removeClass("incorrect-button");
      renderQuestion();
    });
    $(optionC).on("click", function() {
      console.log("wrong button 2");
      console.log("this button is being clicked C");
      incorrect++;
      $("#incorrect").text(incorrect);
      $("#optionC").addClass("incorrect-button");
      $("#optionC").removeClass("incorrect-button");
      renderQuestion();
    });
    $(optionD).on("click", function() {
      console.log("wrong button 3");
      console.log("this button is being clicked D");
      incorrect++;
      $("#incorrect").text(incorrect);
      $("#optionD").addClass("incorrect-button");
      $("#optionD").removeClass("incorrect-button");
      renderQuestion();
    });
  }
})();
```

```css
#container {
  text-align: center;
}

.game-wrapper {
  background: url(../images/background-copy.jpg);
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.card {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4); /* Black w/opacity/see-through */
  color: antiquewhite;
  padding: 150px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.correct-button {
  background-color: green;
}

.incorrect-button {
  background-color: red;
}

#btnNext {
  background-color: black;
}

#score {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4); /* Black w/opacity/see-through */
  color: antiquewhite;
  padding: 150px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,300italic,700,700italic"
    />

    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.css"
    />

    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/milligram/1.3.0/milligram.css"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Trivia Game</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="game-wrapper"></div>
    <div id="container">
      <h1>Trivia Game</h1>
      <div class="card">
        <div id="question"></div>
        <div id="answers">
          <button id="optionA"></button>
          <button id="optionB"></button>
          <button id="optionC"></button>
          <button id="optionD"></button>
        </div>

        <button id="btnNext">NEXT QUESTION</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="score">
      <h1>END RESULTS</h1>
      <p>Correct: <span id="correct">0</span></p>
      <p>Incorrect: <span id="incorrect">0</span></p>
      <p>Unanswered: <span id="unanswered">0</span></p>
    </div>
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script src="assets/javascript/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please put your code here and not on a JSFiddle.  Please see [mre].

Comment: Thanks, will keep these things in mind. Thanks for catching my mistake @CPN Productions

Comment: @GraysonMcMurry you should edit your answer to include your code here. You can still use Jsfiddle but you should also add your code here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the start of your JavaScript file you had

```
  let optionA = $("#optionA");
  let optionB = $("#optionA");
  let optionC = $("#optionA");
  let optionD = $("#optionA");
```

I changed them to

```
  let optionA = $("#optionA");
  let optionB = $("#optionB");
  let optionC = $("#optionC");
  let optionD = $("#optionD");
```

And that fixed your issue!! Sometimes it's the silly little things that get you.